# I have been trying to make a program in C++ that converts fahrenheit to celsius and vice versa using classes and objects

Tags: c++

I would just like to point out that I am new to the boards, so I am sorry if I do something wrong. I am also new to `c++`. I have programmed in `c` before, so the only thing that I am really having trouble with is object oriented programming. I am trying to apply it to a program. I know how to make this program using functions and a `switch` statement, but I am trying to apply object oriented programming to this program idea.

I would like to use a `float` type so that decimals can be entered and printed, but I would be fine using `integers`.

When I run the program, I get extremely larger numbers that do not make sense. These numbers are never the same. Sorry for my lack of comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Celsius{
public:
    float setValue(float c){
        value = c;
    }
    float changeValue(float value){
        returnValue = value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }
    float getValue(){
        return returnValue;
    }
private:
    float value;
    float returnValue;
};

class Fahrenheit{
public:
    float setValue(float f){
        value = f;
    }
    float changeValue(float value){
        returnValue = (value - 32)*5/9;
        cout << returnValue;
    }
    float getValue(){
        return returnValue;
    }
private:
    float value;
    float returnValue;
};


int main()
{
    char type;
    float value1;

    cout << "Do have a celsius or fahrenheit degree? (Press c for celsius and f for fahrenheit.) ";
    cin >> type;
    cout << "Enter a temperature value: ";
    cin >> value1;

    if(type == 'C' || type == 'c'){
        Celsius metricObject;
        metricObject.setValue(value1);
        cout << "In Fahrenheit, that is: " << metricObject.getValue();
    }
    else if(type == 'F' || type == 'f'){
        Fahrenheit englishObject;
        englishObject.setValue(value1);
        cout << "In celsius, that is: " << englishObject.getValue();

    }
    else{
        return(0);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to call `changeValue()` function before printing it out?

Comment: why are you creating classes?  wouldn't two simple functions suffice?  And you should probably look into `constructors`

Comment: 'Object Oriented Programming' doesn't mean just using classes and member functions. Your program is not OOP and especially demonstrates an anti-pattern, getters and setters, that violates one of the core precepts of OOP. There's some controversy over the value of OOP, but it clearly doesn't offer any value in tiny toy programs like this. If you want to learn OOP then I think a pretty good source to start with is [Holub on Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/Holub-Patterns-Learning-Design-Looking/dp/159059388X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing call to changeValue() for both Celcius and Farenheit.

Call changeValue() on metricObject and englishObject before calling getValue(). This should give some sensible values.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised I didn't see that. This question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `returnValue` variable which is not initialized in the course of execution. So, initialized it by calling `changeValue()` if the temperature is being entered in Celsius or Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing your classes like this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Celsius{
public:
    float setValue(float c){
        value = c;
        convertedValue = value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }
    float getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    float getConvertedValue(){
        return convertedValue;
    }
private:
    float value;
    float convertedValue;
};

class Fahrenheit{
public:
    float setValue(float f){
        value = f;
        convertedValue = (value - 32)*5/9;
    }
    float getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    float getConvertedValue(){
        return convertedValue;
    }
private:
    float value;
    float convertedValue;
};


int main()
{
    char type;
    float value1;

    cout << "Do have a celsius or fahrenheit degree? (Press c for celsius and f for fahrenheit.) ";
    cin >> type;
    cout << "Enter a temperature value: ";
    cin >> value1;

    if(type == 'C' || type == 'c'){
        Celsius metricObject;
        metricObject.setValue(value1);
        cout << "In Fahrenheit, that is: " << metricObject.getConvertedValue();
    }
    else if(type == 'F' || type == 'f'){
        Fahrenheit englishObject;
        englishObject.setValue(value1);
        cout << "In celsius, that is: " << englishObject.getConvertedValue();

    }
    else{
        return(0);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This sets `value`, it also calculates and sets `convertedValue`.

You can use `getValue()` to access the original `value`, and `getConvertedValue` to access the `convertedValue()`.